# Limit involving Summation of Trigonometric Functions

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

A friend of mine gave me the following question after struggling with it for quite some time:

> Consider a function defined as below:
>   $$f^k (\theta) =\sum_{r=1}^n \left( \frac{\tan \left( \frac {\theta}{2^r} \right) }{2^r} \right)^k +\frac 1 3 \sum _{r=1}^n \left( \frac { \tan \left( \frac{\theta}{2^r} \right) }{8^r} \right)$$
>   Define another function $$\displaystyle{L(\theta )=\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty }{ \left( \sum _{ k=1 }^{ 3 }{ f^{ k }\left( \theta \right) } \right) } }$$
>   Find $L\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right)$

$$$$

One of the hints given to me was to use the following result:

$$\displaystyle{\prod _{ k=1 }^{ n }{ \cos { \left( \cfrac { \theta }{ { 2 }^{ k } } \right) } } =\cfrac { \sin { \theta } }{ { 2 }^{ n }\sin { \left( \cfrac { \theta }{ { 2 }^{ n } } \right) } } }$$

by converting it into a sum (which can be done by taking the natural logarithm of both sides). 
I struggled with it for some time, but after a while, I realised that it was beyond me to solve this on my own.
$$$$
Could somebody please show me how this question might be solved? Many thanks!